# Is there a property in Oracle 12c Forms to wrap the Menu items?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, weblogic12c, oracleforms

For e.g.

[image]

We will have **more menu items added**, instead of scrolling right and left when we have more menu items.

Is there a property to wrapping the menu items into the new line for Menus for MMB file ?

e.g First line - |Commerical|Costing|Reports|

second line      |Exit|Window|

We do not want our users to be scrolling everytime the window is small or add new menu items to the Menu bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not such a property, but a single menu item can have multiple subitems.  That is, each top-level menu item can have more than one subitem, and thus accomplish more than one thing.